# Django 1.9 How do you filter child's child's model with or statement?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a parent model Catalog and its child model Product and Product's child model Options.
Catalog and Product's relationship is OneToOne and Product and Options's relationship is OneToMany

I'd like to filter if one of Options is met a condition, return Catalog model

here is my code below

```
class Catalog(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(models.Product)

class Product(models.Model):
    objects = ProductManager()

class ProductOptions(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name = 'options')

class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(ProductManager, self).get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.prefetch_related('options')
        return queryset
```

and What I've tried so far is

this query works fine without or statement

```
catalog_query = models.Catalog.objects.all()
catalog_query = catalog_query.filter(product__options__date=datetime(2018,10,24)
```

but when i put or statement, it returns duplicated Catalog data

```
catalog_query = models.Catalog.objects.all()
catalog_query = catalog_query.filter(product__options__date=datetime(2018,10,24) | catalog_query.filter(product__quantity_limit=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need "Q object":
https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

example from documentation:

```
Q(question__startswith='Who') | Q(question__startswith='What')
```

so your example will look like that:

```
from django.db.models import Q

catalog_query = catalog_query.filter(
    Q(product__options__date=datetime(2018,10,24))
    | Q(catalog_query.filter(product__quantity_limit=True))
```

Use ".distinct()" on queryset to remove duplicates:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

Comment: Thanks!!! It works like a charm!! and the function distinct() was What i wanted!!

Comment: I have a question to you, @EricLee:
Your queryset with **OR** and without **Q object** doesn't raise SyntaxError?

Comment: So I don't understand why :D